# Ubuntu VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.3-1410761.i386.bundle doesn't start

Tags: vmware

I am trying to install VMWare Workstation on my Ubuntu but getting the following error, please help

```
  ./VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.3-1410761.i386.bundle 
    Extracting VMware Installer...done.
    Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge": /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
    Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module": libtopmenu-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


    ubuntu in 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:46:51 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Hi all does any one knows a solution for this ?

Comment: If possible, you will fare better with a more current version of VMWare.  If this is not possible, then you will most likely need to apply several patches to this older version - it take some digging, but you will be  able to find them on [VMWare forums](https://communities.vmware.com).  As an alternative, consider using using [KVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help I needed to install a GN3 image but localserver will do the trick still I will try KVM Charles  Thank you